# Fonts display incorrectly in Google Sites but only when publishing to custom domain

Tags: fonts, dns, google-sites

We've done a simple Google Sites and changed some fonts to Montserrat and Helvetica Neue. These fonts display perfectly on the **sites.google.com/view/mysite** page, as you can see below:

[Fonts displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqvwx.png)

However, when using a (previously set up) custom domain to access the website, fonts change to Times New Roman everywhere. I don't have a clue why. HTML code is the same between both websites so we don't know what's going on. If someone is able to guide us a bit, it´d be very appreciated

[Fonts displaying incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjG11.png)

Comment: Open Dev Tools and see if the fonts are being loaded or there are some errors

Comment: In the future, questions like this should be asked at [webmasters.se].

Comment: A safe solution is to select all text in sections that don’t appear properly and select ‘remove all formatting’ option. Change styling only via editing the theme. Refresh custom domain web page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with font rendering differences with a custom domain vs. viewing via sites.google.com. Unfortunately, there is no information about when this might be resolved. (Answer from https://support.google.com/sites/thread/112269932/standard-fonts-not-working-on-published-site?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I use Roboto it is displaying properly for my custom domain. It isn't appearing as Times New Roman everywhere. Maybe it's a fluke and I'll see Times New Roman again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur with a chosen font in a custom theme, with a custom URL. The solution is to **not** have a *second* custom font within the page, which is specifically chosen (uniquely) when writing that page. Stick to choosing the theme font settings.